# Getting NULL Value errors even when there are no null values in the database

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, null

We have an ASPX site that displays charts given stats captured by a server onto a database. Recently, it's giving us a "There is no row at position 0." error and "Index was outside the bounds of the array. " error. We usually get this error when some fields failed to be filled by the capture, thus giving us NULL values. But today, it's giving us these errors despite not having NULL values.

Here are two functions that give us the error:

"Index was outside the bounds of the array" (at this line: *ctrDMX(ctr) = "*")

```
    Public Function Bar_Task_Cat() As String
    Dim Conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(MSSQLstring)
    Conn.Open()

    Dim strUserCode = CType(Session("usrCd"), String)

    Dim SQLstring As String

    If strUserCode = "ADMIN" Then
        SQLstring = "SELECT COUNT(AskAOID) AS credits, CatCode AS category, ProductCode " _
                                & "FROM dbo.AskAO_Stats " _
                                & "WHERE (FirstResponse BETWEEN '" & dpFrom.SelectedDate.ToString & "' AND '" & dpTo.SelectedDate.ToString & "') " _
                                & "AND (FirstResponse IS NOT NULL) AND (CatCode IS NOT NULL) AND (ProductCode IS NOT NULL) " _
                                & "GROUP BY ProductCode, CatCode " _
                                & "ORDER BY CatCode"
    Else
        SQLstring = "SELECT COUNT(AskAOID) AS credits, CatCode AS category, ProductCode " _
                                & "FROM dbo.AskAO_Stats " _
                                & "WHERE (FirstResponse BETWEEN '" & dpFrom.SelectedDate.ToString & "' AND '" & dpTo.SelectedDate.ToString & "') " _
                                & "AND (Deferred = '" & strUserCode & "') " _
                                & "AND (FirstResponse IS NOT NULL) AND (CatCode IS NOT NULL) AND (ProductCode IS NOT NULL) " _
                                & "GROUP BY ProductCode, CatCode " _
                                & "ORDER BY CatCode"
    End If

    Dim SQLcmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SQLstring, Conn)
    Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter(SQLstring, Conn)
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    DA.Fill(DS)

    Conn.Close()

    Dim Def_Color_t(12) As String
    Def_Color_t(0) = "AFD8F8"
    Def_Color_t(1) = "F6BD0F"
    Def_Color_t(2) = "8BBA00"
    Def_Color_t(3) = "FF8E46"
    Def_Color_t(4) = "008E8E"
    Def_Color_t(5) = "D64646"
    Def_Color_t(6) = "8E468E"
    Def_Color_t(7) = "588526"
    Def_Color_t(8) = "B3AA00"
    Def_Color_t(9) = "008ED6"
    Def_Color_t(10) = "9D080D"
    Def_Color_t(11) = "A186BE"
    Def_Color_t(12) = "AFD8F8"


    Dim ctr As Integer = 0
    Dim ctrD As Integer = 0
    Dim ctrM As Integer = 0
    Dim ctrF As Integer = 0
    Dim ctrA As Integer = 0
    Dim ctrO As Integer = 0
    Dim m_ctr As Integer = 0
    Dim m1_ctr As Integer = 0

    Dim strXML As String
    Dim Cat As String
    Dim OldCat As String
    Dim strCatName As String

    Dim ProdCode As String

    'counters for Products
    Dim ctrDMX(12), ctrMHM(12), ctrFCX(12), ctrAPM(12), ctrPOR(12), ctrONL(12), ctrDVX(12), ctrOTH(12) As String

    'counters for Categories
    'Dim ctrOL(12), ctrAR(12), ctrPR(12), ctrST(12), ctrPQ(12), ctrFW(12), ctrOO(12) As String
    Dim ctrAR(12), ctrDA(12), ctrDB(12), ctrDC(12), ctrDD(12), ctrDE(12), ctrDF(12), ctrDG(12), ctrDH(12), ctrDI(12), ctrDJ(12), ctrDK(12) As String
    Dim ctrDL(12), ctrDM(12), ctrDN(12), ctrDO(12), ctrDP(12), ctrDQ(12), ctrFW(12), ctrOL(12), ctrOO(12), ctrPR(12), ctrPQ(12), ctrST(12) As String

    strXML = ""
    Cat = ""
    OldCat = ""
    strCatName = ""

    strXML = strXML & "<chart palette='2' labelDisplay='Rotate' slantLabels='1' showBorder='0' bgColor='FFFFFF,FFFFFF' showPercentValues='1' showPercentInToolTip='1' stack100Percent='1' caption='Percentage of Tasks by Category by Product' shownames='1' showvalues='0' showSum='1' decimals='0' useRoundEdges='1'>"
    strXML = strXML & "<categories>"
    Do Until ctr = DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        Cat = DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("category").ToString
        If Cat <> OldCat Then
            Select Case DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("category").ToString
                Case "AR"
                    strCatName = "AR" 
                Case "DA"
                    strCatName = "DA" 
                Case "DB"
                    strCatName = "DB" 
                Case "DC"
                    strCatName = "DC" 
                Case "DD"
                    strCatName = "DD" 
                Case "DE"
                    strCatName = "DE" 
                Case "DF"
                    strCatName = "DF" 
                Case "DG"
                    strCatName = "DG" 
                Case "DH"
                    strCatName = "DH" 
                Case "DI"
                    strCatName = "DI"
                Case "DJ"
                    strCatName = "DJ" 
                Case "DK"
                    strCatName = "DK" 
                Case "DL"
                    strCatName = "DL" 
                Case "DM"
                    strCatName = "DM" 
                Case "DN"
                    strCatName = "DN" 
                Case "DO"
                    strCatName = "DO" 
                Case "DP"
                    strCatName = "DP" 
                Case "DQ"
                    strCatName = "DQ" 
                Case "FW"
                    strCatName = "FW" 
                Case "OL"
                    strCatName = "OL" 
                Case "OO"
                    strCatName = "OO" 
                Case "PR"
                    strCatName = "PR" 
                Case "PQ"
                    strCatName = "PQ" 
                Case "ST"
                    strCatName = "ST" 
            End Select
            strXML = strXML & "<category label='" & strCatName & "' value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            m_ctr = m_ctr + 1
        End If
        OldCat = Cat
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</categories>"

    'initialize
    ctr = 0

    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        ctrDMX(ctr) = "<set value='0' />" 'This line gives the error
        ctrFCX(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctrMHM(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctrPOR(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctrONL(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctrAPM(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctrDVX(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctrOTH(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop

    ctr = 0
    Cat = ""
    OldCat = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("category").ToString

    Do Until ctr = DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        ProdCode = DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("ProductCode").ToString

        Cat = DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("category").ToString

        If Cat <> OldCat Then
            m1_ctr = m1_ctr + 1
        End If

        Select Case ProdCode
            Case "DMX"
                ctrDMX(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "FCX"
                ctrFCX(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "MHM"
                ctrMHM(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "POR"
                ctrPOR(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "ONL"
                ctrONL(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "APM"
                ctrAPM(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "DVX"
                ctrDVX(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "OTH"
                ctrOTH(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
        End Select

        OldCat = Cat

        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='AMS Device' color='AFD8F8' showValues='0'>" 'Documentation
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrDMX(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='Field Communicator' color='8BBA00' showValues='0'>" 'Documentation
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrFCX(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='Machinery Health' color='F6BD0F' showValues='0'>" 'Documentation
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrMHM(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='Portables' color='AFD8F8' showValues='0'>" 'Documentation
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrPOR(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='Online' color='A186BE' showValues='0'>" 'Documentation
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrONL(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='Asset Portal' color='FF8E46' showValues='0'>" 'Documentation
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrAPM(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='DeltaV' color='9D080D' showValues='0'>" 'Documentation
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrDVX(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='Others' color='008E8E' showValues='0'>" 'Documentation
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrOTH(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    strXML = strXML & "</chart>"

    'Create the chart - Column 3D Chart with data from strXML variable using dataXML method
    Return RenderChartHTML("Charts/NewCharts/StackedColumn3D.swf", "", strXML, "myNext", "450", "500", False)
    'for gauge

End Function
```

"There is no row at position 0" (at this line: *OldMonth = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Month").ToString*)

```
    Public Function FRTChart() As String
    Dim Conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(MSSQLstring)
    Conn.Open()

    Dim strUserCode = CType(Session("usrCd"), String)

    Dim SQLstring As String

    If strUserCode = "ADMIN" Then
        SQLstring = "SELECT Count(FirstResponse) AS TotalQueries, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), FirstResponse, 113), 4, 8) AS Month, RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), FirstResponse , 120), 2) AS Month_Order, CAST(YEAR(FirstResponse) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS Year, " _
                                & "SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, Date_Sent, FirstResponse) <= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LessThan2Hours, " _
                                & "SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, Date_Sent, FirstResponse) between 3 AND 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LessThan24Hours, " _
                                & "SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, Date_Sent, FirstResponse) between 25 AND 48 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LessThan48Hours, " _
                                & "SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, Date_Sent, FirstResponse) between 49 AND 72 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LessThan72Hours, " _
                                & "SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, Date_Sent, FirstResponse) between 73 AND 96 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LessThan96Hours, " _
                                & "SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, Date_Sent, FirstResponse) > 96 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Over96Hours " _
                                & "FROM [AskAO].dbo.AskAO_Stats " _
                                & "WHERE (FirstResponse BETWEEN '" & dpFrom.SelectedDate.ToString & "' AND '" & dpTo.SelectedDate.ToString & "') " _
                                & "AND (Status = 'CLOSED' OR Status = 'ACTIVE') " _
                                & "AND (FirstResponse IS NOT NULL) " _
                                & "GROUP BY SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), FirstResponse , 113), 4, 8), CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), FirstResponse , 120), CAST(YEAR(FirstResponse) AS VARCHAR(4)) " _
                                & "ORDER BY Year, Month_Order"
    Else
        SQLstring = "SELECT Count(FirstResponse) AS TotalQueries, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), FirstResponse, 113), 4, 8) AS Month, RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), FirstResponse , 120), 2) AS Month_Order, CAST(YEAR(FirstResponse) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS Year, " _
                                & "SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, Date_Sent, FirstResponse) <= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LessThan2Hours, " _
                                & "SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, Date_Sent, FirstResponse) between 3 AND 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LessThan24Hours, " _
                                & "SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, Date_Sent, FirstResponse) between 25 AND 48 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LessThan48Hours, " _
                                & "SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, Date_Sent, FirstResponse) between 49 AND 72 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LessThan72Hours, " _
                                & "SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, Date_Sent, FirstResponse) between 73 AND 96 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LessThan96Hours, " _
                                & "SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, Date_Sent, FirstResponse) > 96 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Over96Hours " _
                                & "FROM [AskAO].dbo.AskAO_Stats " _
                                & "WHERE (FirstResponse BETWEEN '" & dpFrom.SelectedDate.ToString & "' AND '" & dpTo.SelectedDate.ToString & "') " _
                                & "AND (Status = 'CLOSED' OR Status = 'ACTIVE') AND (Deferred = '" & strUserCode & "') " _
                                & "AND (FirstResponse IS NOT NULL) " _
                                & "GROUP BY SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), FirstResponse , 113), 4, 8), CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), FirstResponse , 120), CAST(YEAR(FirstResponse) AS VARCHAR(4)) " _
                                & "ORDER BY Year, Month_Order"
    End If

    Dim SQLcmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SQLstring, Conn)
    Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter(SQLstring, Conn)
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    DA.Fill(DS)

    Dim Def_Color_t(12) As String
    Def_Color_t(0) = "AFD8F8"
    Def_Color_t(1) = "F6BD0F"
    Def_Color_t(2) = "8BBA00"
    Def_Color_t(3) = "FF8E46"
    Def_Color_t(4) = "008E8E"
    Def_Color_t(5) = "D64646"
    Def_Color_t(6) = "8E468E"
    Def_Color_t(7) = "588526"
    Def_Color_t(8) = "B3AA00"
    Def_Color_t(9) = "008ED6"
    Def_Color_t(10) = "9D080D"
    Def_Color_t(11) = "A186BE"
    Def_Color_t(12) = "AFD8F8"


    Dim ctr As Integer = 0
    Dim ctrD As Integer = 0
    Dim ctrM As Integer = 0
    Dim ctrF As Integer = 0
    Dim ctrA As Integer = 0
    Dim ctrO As Integer = 0
    Dim m_ctr As Integer = 0
    Dim m1_ctr As Integer = 0

    Dim strXML As String
    Dim CatMonth As String
    Dim OldMonth As String

    Dim ctr2(12), ctr24(12), ctr48(12), ctr72(12), ctr96(12), ctro96(12) As String

    strXML = ""
    CatMonth = ""
    OldMonth = ""

    strXML = strXML & "<chart palette='2' legendPosition='RIGHT' labelDisplay='Rotate' slantLabels='1' showBorder='0' bgColor='FFFFFF,FFFFFF'  caption='First Response Time' shownames='1' showvalues='0' showSum='1' decimals='0' useRoundEdges='1' showPercentValues='1' showPercentInToolTip='1'>"
    strXML = strXML & "<categories>"
    Do Until ctr = DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        CatMonth = DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("Month").ToString
        If CatMonth <> OldMonth Then
            strXML = strXML & "<category label='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("Month").ToString & "' value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("TotalQueries").ToString & "' />"
            m_ctr = m_ctr + 1
        End If
        OldMonth = CatMonth
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</categories>"

    'initialize
    ctr = 0

    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        ctr2(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctr24(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctr48(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctr72(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctr96(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctro96(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop

    ctr = 0
    CatMonth = ""
    OldMonth = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Month").ToString 'This line gives the error

    Do Until ctr = DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        'ProdCode = DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("ProductCode").ToString
        'respTime = DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("ResponseTime")

        CatMonth = DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("Month").ToString

        If CatMonth <> OldMonth Then
            m1_ctr = m1_ctr + 1
        End If

        ctr2(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("LessThan2Hours").ToString & "' />"
        ctr24(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("LessThan24Hours").ToString & "' />"
        ctr48(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("LessThan48Hours").ToString & "' />"
        ctr72(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("LessThan72Hours").ToString & "' />"
        ctr96(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("LessThan96Hours").ToString & "' />"
        ctro96(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("Over96Hours").ToString & "' />"

        OldMonth = CatMonth

        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='2 Hrs' color='AFD8F8' showValues='0'>" 'Documentation
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctr2(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='24 Hrs' color='8BBA00' showValues='0'>" 'Documentation
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctr24(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='24 - 48 Hrs' color='F6BD0F' showValues='0'>" 'Documentation
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctr48(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='48 - 72 Hrs' color='008E8E' showValues='0'>" 'Documentation
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctr72(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='72 - 96 Hrs' color='A186BE' showValues='0'>" 'Documentation
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctr96(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='Over 96 Hrs' color='FF8E46' showValues='0'>" 'Documentation
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctro96(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    strXML = strXML & "</chart>"

    'Create the chart - Column 3D Chart with data from strXML variable using dataXML method
    Return RenderChartHTML("Charts/NewCharts/StackedColumn3D.swf", "", strXML, "myNext", "450", "370", False)
    'for gauge

End Function
```

When I checked the SQL results for the "Admin" account, these are the results:

[image: FRT Chart]
[image: Bar_Task_Cat chart]

There are no NULL values, yet I get those errors in strUserCode = "ADMIN" :( it works fine in Individual users

Please help :( Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error has nothing to do with NULL database values, it has to do with you trying to access an index in an array that is outside the array length.  One thing to keep in mind is that arrays are 0 index based, which means that the first item in the array will be index 0, and then the last item in an array with length of 3 will have an index of 2.

Check anywhere that is accessing a collection using its index, and makes sure that you don't have any code that will step outside of that last index.  Keep in mind that when using loops, the last index will be the Count - 1.

In your first code block that gives the out of bounds exception:

```
Do Until ctr = m_ctr
    ctrDMX(ctr) = "<set value='0' />" 'This line gives the error
```

The `ctrDMX` array is only initialized to contain a max of 13 items, but `m_ctr` is set based on your SQL query results #2 which has many more values (my guess is "admin" user sees more categories?).  Since your values that are going into this array are dynamically generated from the database, you may either have to look at `ReDim`'ing your arrays based on the DB results, or just switch to use something easier like a `List(of String)` where you can call `.Add(myString)` without worrying about the indexes.

For the 2nd exception, you have 0 rows in the table when you are getting to the line:

```
OldMonth = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Month").ToString 'This line gives the error
```

so check the make sure you have at least one row before accessing:

```
If DS.Tables(0).Rows(0) >= 1 Then
    OldMonth = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Month").ToString 'This line gives the error 
Else
    OldMonth = String.Empty
End If
```

One more very important issue that was not in your original question, do NOT build your SQL strings by concatenating string together.  This creates a large SQL Injection vulnerability on your website.  Use SQL Parameters for your filter values. Instead of having things like `"WHERE (FirstResponse BETWEEN '" & dpFrom.SelectedDate.ToString & "' AND '" & dpTo.SelectedDate.ToString & "') "` in your SQL String, change it to `"WHERE (FirstResponse BETWEEN @dateFrom AND @dateTo) "`

and then add parameter values to your SQLCommand: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Dim SQLcmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SQLstring, Conn)
SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateFrom", dpFrom.SelectedDate)
SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTo", dpTo.SelectedDate)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, as well as for the extra tip! Yeah, I thought it was NULL values, but it turned out that they added some ProductCodes and CategoryCodes without informing us :( I changed the codes accordingly :) Thanks again :)